# CSS animation is bugged on certain position values

Tags: javascript, css

So, I have an element that transitions when hovering. However, there is a weird flickering bug when using some of the position values. It is very very weird and I've never seen anything like this.
Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

**works:**
absolute, relative,

**does not work:**
fixed, sticky, static

Comment: even though you did not provide any code so we can get the idea of what is happening here. i assume you experience an issue where you hover an item, change its position so it moves away from under your cursor. reverting it back to its normal state(since its no longer being hovered), only to start with the hover again since your mouse is at the "default state". meaning it will "flicker"?

Comment: You are right, I did not add any code. But I am not moving this element. I figured out meanwhile, that adding any kind of Y translate like this: "transform: translate(0px, 1px);" works around this issue for some really weird reason.